# why i keep getting undefined when i console.log this function

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Hello I'm a complete beginner in node js and I just learned about promises and I'm trying to using them in my code
but when I try to console.log this function I keep getting undefined and I don't know why
I will be very thankful if you help me**

```
function weather(location) {
    const request = require('request');
    const errorMessage = 'Something went wrong. Please check you internet connection or the URL you provided.';
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const geoUrl = `https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/
    ${location}.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic3F1YXJlc2NyaXB0IiwiYSI6ImNrc3lwZmdtejFpdzQycHB1eTVpODNwdmYifQ.izw6cVMKDZme4KJwxHdxjw`;

        request({
            url: geoUrl,
            json: true
        }, (error, request) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(errorMessage)
            } else {
                resolve(`http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=
            c704f108fc10fbbdb15c384daff85a20&query=${request.body.features[0].center.reverse()}`)
            }
        })
    }).then(url => {
        request({
            url: url,
            json: true
        }, (error, request) => {
            if (error) {
                return errorMessage
            } else {
                const currData = request.body.current;
                return `${currData.weather_descriptions[0]}, It's currently ${currData.temperature} degrees out. There is a ${currData.humidity}% chance of rain.`;
            }
        });
    }).catch(message => message)
};
console.log(weather('NYC'))
```

Comment: it seems that you have missed "return" statement, it should be return new Promise(...) also I don't think you need to wrap request with a Promise because it already return a promise. Take a look to promise chaining, it would make the code looks nicer

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the promise..

```
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
```

And then the console will log "Unresolved promise." Or something like that. If you want to wait for the promise to resolve, you need to use `await` or the `then` method:

```
weather('NYC').then(console.log)
```

You also need to make sure your promise is being resolved or rejected:

```
if (error){reject(errorMessage)}
else {
    const currData=request.body.current;
    resolve(`${currData.weather_descriptions[0]}, It's currently ${currData.temperature} degrees out. There is a ${currData.humidity}% chance of rain.`);
}
```

All these little errors would be easier to spot if your code was formatted properly.

Also, don't put your private access tokens in public forums.

You can find lots of tutorials on how promises work around the internet. Here's the [MDN manual page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).